# Hide specific cells in a row in VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba

I see Hidden is an "EntireRow" attribute. Is there a way to hide just one cell in a row. My attempts so far have resulted in exceptions.
"Unable to set hidden property of Range class"

```
Range("A23").Hidden = false 'fails
Range("A23").EntireRow.Hidden = false 'Hides entire row, not what I want
```

Comment: You can't hide just one cell. That would create a black-hole in your spreadsheet, opening it to the dark side. May the force be with you.

Comment: You could change the font color to white to change the visibility.

Comment: Thanks.iDevelop and @Jason_Walker. The white knight (space) came to my rescue

Comment: You can also use `Format Cell / Protection / Hidden` which prevents the formula or data to appear in the edit bar when you click in the cell. But that only works while you activate sheet protection, young padawan.

Comment: @iDevelop thanks again. Padawan yes, young I wish :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Jason_Walker and Patrick Honorez.
Hide only works on columns and rows.
I changed the font color to match the fill to 'hide' the cell.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to to hide a **single cell** and do not want to hide the entire row, then hide the column.

Answer (score 0):

As bilbo_strikes_back said "You can't hide just one cell. You could change the font color to white to change the visibility

If Range("A16") = "" Then

```
Range("B16:I16").Font.Color = vbWhite
```

Else

```
Range("B16:I16").Font.Color = vbBlack
```

End If